# I have a LinearLayout has many buttons with different properties.want to have around 90 same layouts of with different text

Tags: android-layout

I have a LinearLayout which has many buttons with different properties. But I want to have around 90 same layouts of with different text and values. Help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right, you want to have a linear layout with 90 different buttons ? correct? if so then this may help (go to your layout Text Editor and paste this (copy and paste more button as required ):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 2"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 3"/>

// copy and  paste here more buttons

</LinearLayout>
```